# Changing PostgreSQL server changed Django app characteristics

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-orm, amazon-aurora

I had to switch an enterprise Django 1.11 site from a corporate-hosted PostgreSQL 9.4 server to AWS RDS Aurora-PostgreSQL 10 cluster. My initial impression was that it should be a straightforward migration, as I was not using any version-specific code.

Immediately after migration, the site started breaking down horribly. Queries that used to take milliseconds suddenly jumped to 100x the time, causing timeouts all over gunicorn threads. I also kept seeing connections being dropped from both RDS and Django.

It kept appearing as if it would be some setting I need to match between previous server and current server, but despite engaging PostgreSQL experts and AWS support, there were no simple answers (or even complex ones). I finally had to fine-tune most queries in my Django code to bring stability to the site.

The app has several queries that refer to foreign relationships, so I used a number of prefetch_related and similar tricks to fix the slowdown. So, a query that was taking 0.5 seconds went to 80 seconds, and after I added prefetch_related, went back to 0.5 seconds.

Even though the site is now stable, I am posting this in the hope that some PostgreSQL and/or Django expert sees this and recognizes this as a symptom of some wrong setting. I am not in a position to share sample queries and am not asking for query optimization. The question is: what would cause a query to become 100x slower when we move from one PostgreSQL server to another, with no change in application code?

Answer (score 1):

In general, postgres-compatible aurora has wildly different performance characteristics than vanilla postgres, and the configuration and tuning for both can be very different.  The easiest path forward for you would have been for you to have used AWS RDS for Postgres and not AWS RDS with Aurora Postgres if you had wanted to get performance characteristics that were close to your self-hosted postgres.  There are a number of configuration details that you didn't share that would affect performance between RDS and a self-hosted server including VPC settings, SSL, etc. that could also affect performance.

Comment: Do you have any references to back the comment that postgres-compatible aurora has wildly different performance characteristics?